# What does this syntax means?

Tags: vba, syntax

Hello I would like to know what exactly the (4) stands for in this loop
thank you

```
For i= 8 To Split(sheetXls.UsedRange.Address, "$")(4)
```

Comment: It's simply indexing the array returned by `Split`.

Comment: It's saying to loop from 8 to whatever number is the fifth element in `sheetXls.UsedRange.Address`, when separated by `$` as a delimiter.

Comment: Considering your use of `sheetXls` you're probably using VBA with Excel. In either case, please do some research about Basic, there are probably millions of references and tutorials all over the Internet which should be able to teach you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Means: from row 8 to last used row of sheetXls